# Error uploading a file using Selenium chromedriver (Python) – "Invalid file extension selected"

Tags: python, selenium, upload

I'm using Selenium Chrome webdriver on Python 3.8

Trying to automate uploading a file. When I use the file picker from the webdriver, I'm getting an error from the website: "Invalid file extension selected". When I select the same file manually, it works. Also it's a permitted file extension for the website (pdf).

Here is the section of code immediately preceding where the error arises:

```
file_input = browser.find_element_by_css_selector(
    '[aria-label="select file to upload"]')
path = f'{os.getcwd()}\\Memo Style.pdf'
file_input.send_keys(path)
```

Here is what the website shows when I run it:

[Invalid file extension selected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jA5Gk.png)

Here is the html from the website that generates the file chooser:

```
<div data-role="input-control" class="input-control text">
<input aria-label="select file to upload" multiple="multiple" type="file" 
accept=".3GP,.AAC,.AIFF,.ASF,.AVI,.BMP,.DMG,.DOC,.DOCX,.DRC,.F4V,.FLAC,
.FLV,.GIF,.ISO,.JPEG,.JPG,.M2TS,.M4A,.M4P,.M4V,.MKV,.MOV,.MP2,.MP3,.MP4,
.MPA,.MPC,.MPEG,.MPG,.MTS,.NSV,.OGA,.OGG,.ONE,.ONEPKG,.PDF,.PNG,.PPT,
.PPTX,.PSD,.QT,.ROQ,.RTF,.SVG,.SVI,.TIFF,.TXT,.VOB,.VOX,.VSD,.WAV,.WEBM,
.WMA,.WMV,.XLS,.XLSX,.FLS,.AVE" class="file-upload">
</div>
```

I don't really know what to try to fix it.
I can get the upload working using pyautogui but obviously it would be preferable to avoid that.

Comment: Is it working if you upload manually

Comment: path = f'"{os.getcwd()}\\Memo Style.pdf"' can you try this

Comment: @PDHide Yes it is working if I upload manually. Tried the double-quotes suggestion and it had the same result.